# Define a nullable reference type property using TypeBuilder/PropertyBuilder

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I'm using TypeBuilder and PropertyBuilder to create Types at runtime (.NET 6).

I need to specify that my property has a nullable reference type:
public MyReferenceType? MyProperty { get; set; }

I have found that the compiler is doing it under the hood with a custom attribute "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute" but it seems that this attribute is also created at compile time and it does not exist somewhere else where I can just add it to my newly created property.

Does someone know how can we do that?

Comment: Have a look here, to see how nullable is compiled: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgxAdgrgGwQQwEYIKYAIMzZgWAChiABAZi1ICYsBhLAb2K1axbYvoH4sBZAJ4AFAE4B7AA4YRAFwFMsAcwwyA3FgDOK9QF8OrYjqA=

Comment: @thehennyy , it produces this NullableAttribute , the interesting thing, is that if you copy the generated NullableAttribute and put it in the code, it will reuse it and not produce it a second time. I'm wondering if it will not mess with something if I put that in my code and reference is as a custom attribute... I'll give it a try...

Comment: @yeska Did you find a way to implement this? I can't even reflect `NullableAttribute`'s constructor to pass it to `SetCustomAttribute` on a field builder.